# Treat Picture Like a Map ASP/CSHTML

Tags: c#, image, razor, maps, zooming

I need to zoom in and out of a picture, grab it and browse different parts of it as you would a map, and set pushpins as markers to remind me of locations I found interesting. Essentially I want to perform similar functionality that bing (or google) maps provides but on a picture I have. From this tutorial : http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-bing-maps-api
I have tried swapping the source to point to the picture on my local drive but that don't work. What would be a good language / approach to take/use in solving this issue? I was trying to do this in C# first but now need to do this for a web application, please advise; newbie to Web development btw...

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to understand why are you trying to view Picture as Map; zooming, clicking, dragging. But however, try to use jQuery for this.

The API that you are using, would work for Bing Maps. Its their server API and I don't think you can use that for any other work. But you can still re-write it and compile it to work for you.

The basic code or what you can say, the basic events for it would be `.click()` `.dblclick()` then you can use [jQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). These would be the basics only.

However if you are working with image. You would definitely need some other tools that would be able to let you work with Images, try [SilverLight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/).

You mentioned Google Maps, Bing Maps, I need to clarify they use huge amount of JavaScript. To check where click was made, what is its location, where to zoom in where to zoom out. If it was me, I would have first tried to learn jQuery and JavaScript. To learn what are events, how they are used, and how I can use them in my project.

jQuery zoom is nothing or should I say, there is no such thing as a Zoom for any object in jQuery API. But this is a great site that I just found right now I hope it would be a kick start for you [jQuery Zoom jacklmoore.com](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/). For this site, you might need some plugin from the person, link is provided on that page! Go an have a look. :)

**Again:** Try to learn the basics first. You never know when the very basic event is needed and you are trying to use the expert level one. I hope it helps! :) Comment for any question or any objection.

Cheers.